# Powershell ScriptBlock Not Executing

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to execute code on a remote machine using `invoke-command`. Part of that method includes a `ScriptBlock` parameter, and I get the sense that I'm not doing something correctly.

First I tried to create a method in the script, which looked like this:

```
param([string] $filename)

function ValidatePath( $file, $fileType = "container" )
{
    $fileExist = $null
    if( -not (test-path $file -PathType $fileType) )
    {               
        throw "The path $file does not exist!"
        $fileExist = false
    }
    else
    {
        echo $filename found!
        $fileExist = true
    }
    return $fileExist
}


$responseObject = Invoke-Command -ComputerName MININT-OU9K10R
    -ScriptBlock{validatePath($filename)} -AsJob

$result = Receive-Job -id $responseObject.Id

echo $result
```

To call this, I would do `.\myScriptName.ps1  -filename C:\file\to\test`. The script would execute, but would not call the function.

Then I thought that maybe I should put the function into a new script. This looked like:

File 1:

```
$responseObject = Invoke-Command -ComputerName MININT-OU9K10R -ScriptBlock {
  .\file2.ps1 -filename C:\something } -AsJob

$result = Receive-Job -id $responseObject.Id

echo $result
```

File 2:

```
Param([string] $filename)
```

Neither of these approaches will execute the function and I'm wondering why; or, what I need to do to make it work.

```
function ValidatePath( $file, $fileType = "container" )
{
    $fileExist = $null
    if( -not (test-path $file -PathType $fileType) )
    {               
        throw "The path $file does not exist!"
        $fileExist = false
    }
    else
    {
        echo $filename found!
        $fileExist = true
    }
    return $fileExist
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Invoke-Command executes the code in the script block on the remote computer. The ValidatePath function is not defined on the remote computer, and the script file **file2.ps1** does not exist there. There is nothing that gives the remote computer access to the code in the script that executes Invoke-Command or to files on the computer on which the script is running. You'd need to either copy **file2.ps1** to the remote computer, or provide it a UNC path to a share on your computer where the file is available, or put the contents of the ValidatePath function in the script block. Be sure to change all instances of **$file** to **$filename** or vice versa and adapt the code to run interactively, for example you'd eliminate **$fileExist** and the **return** statement.

To put the path-validating code in the scriptblock that gets passed to the remote computer, you'd do something like this:

```
$scriptblock = @"
  if (-not (Test-Path $filename -PathType 'Container') ) {
    throw "The path $file does not exist!"
  } else {
    echo $filename found!
  }
"@

$responseObject = Invoke-Command -ComputerName MININT-OU9K10R -ScriptBlock{$scriptblock} -AsJob
```

**N.B.** Make sure the **"@** is not indented. It *must* be at the beginning of the line.

BTW, although this is moot, what's the point of setting a variable immediately after a **throw** statement? Once you throw an error, the function terminates. `$fileExist = false` would never execute under any circumstances. You probably wanted to use **Write-Error**.

Comment: What would the scriptblock look like if I used the UNC path?

Comment: You'd use a UNC path if you put your script in a file. Instead of `.\file2.ps1`, which is a relative path to a local file that the remote computer doesn't have access to (it would look for the file in its own default working directory), you'd create a share on your computer, put the script file there, and use a path that looks like `\\yourcomputer\share\file2.ps1`. You'd probably be better off putting your code in the ScriptBlock where you're trying to call the ValidatePath function, because that code gets passed to the remote computer. That won't fit in a comment, I'll add it to the answer.