# Pass in a function to a Invoke-Command scriptBlock

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a function then call the function when I pass it to the Invoke-Command -scriptBlock. However, when I run this it says that it cannot recognize that function

```
Function Feature 
{
   # Install Features
   Add-WindowsFeature as-dist-transaction,as-was-support , fs-fileserver, web-server,web-webserver,web-app-dev,web-dav-publishing,web-http-redirect,web-http-tracing,web-lgcy-mgmt-console,web-metabase, web-mgmt-compat,web-mgmt-service,web-scripting-tools,web-dyn-compression,web-windows-auth,net-http-activation,net-non-http-activ, rsat-web-server, telnet-client, SNMP-Service
   # Agent Contact
   reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent" /v sysContact /t REG_SZ /d "Production Team" /f
   # Agent Location
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent" /v sysLocation /t REG_SZ /d "Pleasant Hill" /f
# Agent Services (all)
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent" /v sysServices /t REG_DWORD /d 79 /f
# Community Name
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\!snmp%AM!" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d "amprdsys04.assetmark.com" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities" /v "!snmp%AM!" /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
# Restart the SNMP Service
restart-service snmp
# Configure the Windows Management Instrumentation service recovery time
sc.exe failure Winmgmt reset= 86400 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/none/60000
# Install Other Required Features
D:\Install\ASPNetMVC3\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe /i
# end
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer123-ScriptBlock {Feature}
```

Comment: To make this even more PowerShell-like, you can replace all the `reg add` commands with `Set-Itemproperty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a function to define a script block you can call by name, usually repeatedly.  There doesn't seem to be any reason to use a function for what you're doing here, and it's just complicating the process. Just make it a script block, and invoke that:

```
$InstallFeatures =
{
   # Install Features
   Add-WindowsFeature as-dist-transaction,as-was-support , fs-fileserver, web-server,web-webserver,web-app-dev,web-dav-publishing,web-http-redirect,web-http-tracing,web-lgcy-mgmt-console,web-metabase, web-mgmt-compat,web-mgmt-service,web-scripting-tools,web-dyn-compression,web-windows-auth,net-http-activation,net-non-http-activ, rsat-web-server, telnet-client, SNMP-Service
   # Agent Contact
   reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent" /v sysContact /t REG_SZ /d "Production Team" /f
   # Agent Location
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent" /v sysLocation /t REG_SZ /d "Pleasant Hill" /f
# Agent Services (all)
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\RFC1156Agent" /v sysServices /t REG_DWORD /d 79 /f
# Community Name
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\TrapConfiguration\!snmp%AM!" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d "amprdsys04.assetmark.com" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SNMP\Parameters\ValidCommunities" /v "!snmp%AM!" /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f
# Restart the SNMP Service
restart-service snmp
# Configure the Windows Management Instrumentation service recovery time
sc.exe failure Winmgmt reset= 86400 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/none/60000
# Install Other Required Features
D:\Install\ASPNetMVC3\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe /i
# end
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer123 -ScriptBlock $InstallFeatures
```

Comment: OK.  Help me understand what advantage there is to making them functions as opposed to simply being a script block assigned to a variable.  Either one can be recalled in the invoke command.

Comment: The function provider is there to support using script blocks as functions to the local session.  The script block is the same whether it's stored in a function or in a variable.  If it's being created as a function, but never invoked as a function in the local session then you're just abusing the function provider by making it a dumping ground for your remote script blocks.

Comment: You're creating a local function, then having to pry the script block out of it to send to a remote server to run.  I don't see how that's "simpler".

Comment: In fact, it occurred to me that a while back [I answered essentially the same question with essentially the same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583103/powershell-scriptblock-not-executing/17583551#17583551). The only difference is that I assigned the contents of the script to a string and interpolated it into curly braces later. This way is better, because it saves four keystrokes and makes the formatting neater. I must have written that answer before I learned that you can assign a scriptblock to a variable directly.

Comment: further more, I understood what he was saying. He didn't understand my question as do you! Again the question was this: "how to call a function in a scriptblock?" I guess that's very hard to understand?

Comment: @Spontaneous1980 I think you're stuck in this argument because you *simplified your question too much*.  If there is a concrete reason why this answer does not work for you, you should edit your question so that it is more like your real code -- enough to demonstrate what you need to do that you can't with this approach.

Comment: @Spontaneous1980 Oh, I understand ***fully*** on what grounds you've convinced yourself that you're right. However, you're wrong on *every* count--logically, behaviorally, and technically. If I feel like it I'll come back and explain in detail why you're wrong in thinking your question wasn't answered and why none of the reasons you've given for needing a function are valid, but for now I'll leave you with this one hint: Take a look at the name of the parameter. There's a *reason* it's called "ScriptBlock".

Comment: @Zack Well, sort of. He's blaming others for his own failure to effectively express what he's trying to accomplish, and is basing his certitude that we're not understanding his question on a logical fallacy; but the really funny thing is that even if he had been more specific to begin with, the correct answer would be the same! He doesn't get that all his objections are rooted in the limits of his understanding of PowerShell, and he's staying willfully ignorant by arguing and getting sarcastic instead of having a constructive conversation and trying to learn.

Comment: @Adi Inbar - sooner or later he's going to encounter the term "anonymous function", and maybe the lights will come on.

Comment: @Zack; you're right I have been very esoteric. I am calling a function that has conditional statements: IE if, while, and switch. The functions will determine and manipulating the output for each server. However, Adi Inbar and Mijolinor are corrected if you're passing static arguments that do nothing else but do like a simple get or set commands. However, that is not what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to manipulate the function, I guess you could do a variable that calls the function before and try to pass in data to the function but I have yet to get that work?

Comment: Example: Function arg($data, $data2){while($data){ if($data2{} else{$data=False}}

Comment: also, my functions have a return in some of them that pass data back.

Comment: To both of you, I am sorry for the miscommunication and lack of respect.

Comment: @Spontaneous1980 Apology accepted.  Now, I think what you haven't grasped is that parameters are an intrinsic part of script blocks, not something that is added or enabled by making it a function.  Any script block can have parameters and have arguments passed to it when it's invoked.

Comment: @mjolinor - I understand that concept. However, I have a website that calls a local service that calls the main PowerShell script. That script calls a module that has about 378 functions in it. The main scripts gets paramaters that is passed to functions with in the module, that module then dictates what other functions to call in order to configure each server. There are about 80 different configurations. I was trying to make two invoke commands. One retrieved data from that and put it into an arrayed variable. That variable then is manipulated and passes the output to all the other functions

Comment: Did whoever designed this module intend for it to be loaded and run locally on the server that's being configured?

Comment: That makes more sense, but I think I'd have done it differently.  We need to get this out of comments, though.  You can contact me directly if you wish. [string](0..33|%{[char][int](46+("686552495351636652556262185355647068516270555358646562655775 0645570").substring(($_*2),2))})-replace " "

Comment: I changed the way the invoke statements goes. I now pass a variable into the invoke statement. I then set my variable for the functions. I.E. $var = siteCore $drv $iis $sql $pgFl $dskPrt invoke-command -computerName $cname -ScriptBlock {$var }. This seems to work better and look cleaner. I like the suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer123-ScriptBlock ${Function:Feature}
```

Comment: And that's basically the same as the answer you already got... Content of `function:` item is a script block, that was used to define it. You just used variable/ provider syntax to access this content.